# In bash, how do I trim a certain section of a string?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm trying to trim only the left half of a string that is given to `ltrim()` as an argument. This is my current code.

```
ltrim()
{
        string=${1}
        divider=$((${#string} / 2))

        trimrule=${2}

        string_left=${string:0:$divider}
        string_right=${string:$divider}

        echo ${string:$divider} ## My own quick debug lines
        echo ${string:0:$divider} ## My own quick debug lines

        if [ $# -ne 2 ]
        then
                printf "%d argument(s) entered. 2 required.\n" "$#"
        else
                while :
                do
                        case $string_left in
                        ${2}*) string_left=${string_left#?} ;;
                        *${2}) string_left=${string_left%?} ;;
                        *) break ;;
                        esac
                done
                printf "Left side string is %s\n" "${string_left}"
        fi
}
```

However, when I enter `ltrim abcdefghijklmnopq abc` the shell returns the following:

```
ijklmnopq 
abcdefgh 
Left side string is bcdefgh
```

So I only lost 'a' out of the word while I'm looking to get 'defgh' as a result. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your logic as implemented will only work with a single char "rule". You need to remove as many chars as there are in the rule at each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function substr_remove() {
    echo "${1//$2/}"
}

substr_remove carfoobar123foo456 foo
```

Output:

```
carbar123456
```

Comment: substr_remove is better.

Comment: Yeah, got it. You are right! I'm still not fluent with the string manipulation operators, I used too much `sed` and `awk`. Currently trying to get fluent with them..

Comment: Just FYI with substring replacement, the closing `/` is presumed. So `${1//$2/}` and `${1//$2}` are equivalent. Also note, to make a single replacement of `$2` in `$1` the form is `${1/$2/}`. With a double `/` (i.e. `${1//$2/}`), that replaces all occurrences of `$2` in `$1`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you searching for something like this?

```
function ltrim() {
    echo ${1##$2}
}

ltrim abcdefghijklmnopq abc # Prints: defghijklmnopq
```

Comment: Oh awesome! But what if I use `ltrim abcdefghijklmnopq def`? Will it print `abcghijklmnopq`?

Comment: @RizkyFakkel No, it will leave the string untouched. (Try it)

Comment: @RizkyFakkel: What is the desired output?

Comment: @Cyrus Yes I did, I can apply this to my script so that only `abcdefgh` is trimmed, but only if it trims out the word from the string. @hek2mgl I'm actually looking for a solution where all instances of the `$2` argument are removed from the string in the `$1` argument. So `ltrim abcstringstringabc abc` becomes `stringstringabc`

Comment: Why do you call the method `ltrim` ?

Comment: Because it 'trims the left half of the entered string'.

Comment: But in the comment before you are expected that the `abc` even from the right side of the string should getting removed. Currently I'm not really sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I didn't mean that, as you can see I showed that `abc` should be removed from only the left half of the string. It should still be there at the end: `stringstringabc`

Comment: This is not really true. Cyrus' answer will replace all occurrences of `abc` while my answer will remove `abc` only if it appears on the left side of the string. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Oh yes I just noticed that. In that case, Cyrus' answer is what I am looking for. My bad, I just tested both again a moment ago.

Comment: Are you really sure that you know what you want??? Please read your recent comments and the last comment again.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that Cyrus's answer was exactly what I need. I formulated my comment incorrectly when I tried to explain what I'm trying to do.